# Hibernate pagination with updating records

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, pagination

I have an paginated HQL query which fetches the records from a table with status NEW or FAILED :

```
public List<Integer> getPendingItems(int channelId, int start, int pageSize) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "select cit.id 
             from Item cit 
             where cit.channel.id = :channelId and (cit.statusCode = 'NEW' or cit.statusCode = 'FAILED')");
    query.setParameter("channelId", channelId);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    query.setFirstResult(start);
    return query.list();
}
```

The initial records returned by this query are processed by a service but the problem is, statusCode of the records is updated to either 'SUCCESS' or 'FAILED'. So next time, pagination goes for a toss because the query would no longer yield the same result set.

Any idea how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Integer> getPendingItems(int channelId, int start, int pageSize) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "select cit.id 
             from Item cit 
             where cit.channel.id = :channelId and (cit.statusCode = 'NEW' or cit.statusCode = 'FAILED' or ID = 'successId' or ID = 'otherSuccessId' or ID = 'thirdSuccessId')");
    query.setParameter("channelId", channelId);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    query.setFirstResult(start);
    return query.list();
}
```

My edit is the part where it says:

> or ID = 'successId' or ID = 'otherSuccessId' or ID = 'thirdSuccessId'

I am suggesting that you COULD keep track of which IDs changed from 'new/failed' to 'success' in your client. Anyway, it's just a suggestion... my real feeling is that if the data set changed, then maybe your pagination isn't really off and you're just thinking about it the wrong way.